# html layout: how to float divs vertically

Tags: html, css, layout

How do I get divs to float vertically like in this picture:

[image]

Background: I have a grid of checkboxes with content sorted alphabetically and I'd like to have alphabetic order progress vertically (since horizontal order is quite hard to follow). All the divs have same size (width like picture, height = 1 line size).

**Update:** To clarify: The main intention is to have a table layout with a variable amount of columns based on available screen width and have the cells in *column-major* order. The actual number of divs is not known in advance.

Comment: I assume the HTML order is div1, div2, div3 etc?

Comment: Do you know the number of `</div>`s in advance?

Comment: I cannot come up with a solution without using Javascript. With CSS only this could be hard

Comment: You could use columns I suppose: [columns on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/columns) and [columns on canIuse](http://caniuse.com/#search=columns)

Comment: @gvee: no, the content can have any number of checkboxes

Comment: @BillAskaga do you know the number of columns in advance?

Comment: I'm not sure this can be done without some sort of Javascript.

Answer (score 5):

**CSS**

```
.cols {
        width:20%;
        float:left;
    }
    .rows {
        height:100px;
    }
```

**HTML**

```
 <div class="cols">
        <div class="rows">Div 1</div>
        <div class="rows">Div 2</div>
        <div class="rows">Div 3</div>
    </div>

    <div class="cols">
        <div class="rows">Div 4</div>
        <div class="rows">Div 5</div>
        <div class="rows">Div 6</div>
    </div>

    <div class="cols">
        <div class="rows">Div 7</div>
    </div>
```

Comment: consider adding some explanation too!! :)

Comment: This isn't correct, the OP said there can be any amount of boxes. This wouldn't work.

Comment: The same result can also be achieved with a good old table. As soon as you add the min-width (like explicitly specified in my question) your solution breaks as it doesn't float single elements but the whole column.

Comment: @ruddy: There has to be fixed amount of boxes in vertical and horizontal. You can not place unlimited box in a 1024 px page. This is just the structure. Someone can easily modify it according to need.

Comment: @DipakKumarPusti You have completely missed what the OP is asking for. Try reading the question again.

Comment: @DipakKumarPusti All you have done is made a pretty bad table using `div`. Again that's not what the OP is asking for. That's what they are trying to avoid.

Comment: @Ruddy : May be, why don't you deliver him a good result. That would be more appreciated.

Comment: @DipakKumarPusti Because they OP has stated in the question that this should be done with HTML and CSS. As I don't know a way to do this without the use of JavaScript I cannot do much more. I have already said in a comment I don't think it can be done without JavaScript.

Answer (score 4):

If you are willing to set a fix height on the table holding the cells you could use flexbox.

Set your holding container to:

```
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
flex-wrap: wrap;
```

And your child elements to:

```
flex-grow: 20%;
min-width: 200px;
```

See the pen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qIpAl

Answer (score 2):

@KunJ : compatibility of grid layout is very bad... ie10 + only, 
http://caniuse.com/css-grid

I think without JS you can't do the tricks, I had the same problem, in order to resolve them, I've load all elements, count them et replace in the good  div

Comment: I fear you are right. Obviously html/css cannot achieve the very task it was made for. Things like this, the default crazy box model, and the impossibility to have same-height float div columns without dirty hacks really make me think that the main intention of the html/css designers was to drive as many people as possible into total insanity!!!

Answer (score 1):

Although the following is not a complete solution, maybe others can build on it to achieve the necessary result:

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/7JD3y/)**

### Markup

Divs wrapped in a container div

### CSS

```
div
{
    width: 100px;
    height: 50px;
    background: orange;
    border: 1px solid yellow;
    display:block;    
}
div:nth-child(4n)
{
    display:table-cell;   
}
.container
{
    display:table;
    width: 100%;
}
```